# Dividing <tr> count to 2 pages without Pagination script

Tags: php

i retrieve 30 datas from my db. What i want is that last 15 must be showed in a different link.

for example

http:/myurk/management/feedback/2

in my framework,

how can i do that?

Comment: and I have no idea what happened there :|

Comment: `2 pages without Pagination` - interesting concept... How does one paginate, without paginating?

Comment: You want to do pagination in other words, right?You can have a look at here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: are your data in a cursor|array|ressource?

Comment: By the way, if you want just 15 why do you take 30? I am not sure, this is exactly that what you want but here's simple script that takes last 15 notes `$result = mysql_query('select * from table_name order by id desc limit 15; while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) { //do what you want with data }`

Comment: How did you retrieve the first 30 ?

Answer (score 0):

Take the last part of the url as an argument and us it to add an offset to your db query.